# Обновление страницы после window.close()

Tags: javascript

Использую 
    window.open('https://oauth.vk.com/authorize

Для входа через вк на сайт. 
Затем закрываю методом window.close().

Вопрос таков как обновить главную страницу с которой запускался window.open.

Answer (score 1):

[window.location](http://javascript.ru/window-location)

Comment: <script>window.close(); window.location.reload();</script> Страница закрывается, но главная не обновляется

Comment: так вам очевидно надо `window.parent.location.reload();window.close();`

Comment: Увы, но нет. Всё равно не обновляется

Comment: тогда так http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/22emV/